# How to fix Gradle build fail, Caused by adding GooglePlayGame Plugin to the game. Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build.gradle, android-manifest, google-play-games

I am trying to add google leaderboard to my game. But when I add the GooglePlayGamePlugin to my game, it fails to build. For the last two days, I am trying to solve this without any success.

I am using

1. AudienceNetwork(facebook) plugin
2. FacebookSDK
3. GooglePlayGames Plugin
4. UnityAds

I know this is caused by GooglePlayGamePlugin because when I remove the plugin, it builds without any error.

Error 1

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:187 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Error 2

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Error 3

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.2.18f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformDexWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/coreui/BuildConfig;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
]
stdout[
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:checkReleaseManifest
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseManifest
:preReleaseBuild
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseAidl
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseRenderscript
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResValues
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseManifest
:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:platformAttrExtractor
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:javaPreCompileRelease
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseShaders
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseShaders
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseAssets
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:mergeReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseResources
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseSources
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:javaPreCompileRelease
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:compileReleaseSources
:lintVitalRelease
:transformClassesWithPreDexForRelease
:transformDexWithDexForRelease FAILED
36 actionable tasks: 27 executed, 9 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I am new to Unity, hence any insight to solve this problem will be a gem for my learning process. Thank you. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I built the game again, but this time deleting AudienceNetwork Plugin and keeping GooglePlayGames plugin. And it builds without any error. Now, what conflict could be happening between these two plugins.  

And, how could I build the game keeping both the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a .jar file being included and used by multiple plugins, or if the plugins use different versions of the same .jar file. this will cause the build to fail as it does't know which version to use.

When you have both plugins in your project go to `/Assets/Plugins/Android/` directory and see if there are any .jar files that are duplicates, or different versionings.

An example could be "audio360-exo28.jar" and "audio360-exo26.jar" both being in there. If this is the case delete either one of them (I'd suggest removing the oldest version first) and try building again (make a backup of the file before you delete it, as it isn't always obvious which are a duplicate)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have one question, do you mean .aar files, because in unity I cannot find any .jar files